# How can I scroll by 100 vh every component in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to create a scrolling effect every 100vh. I have 3 components, each is 100 vh high and I would like the user to switch to the next of these three components every time he scrolls.

Comment: The CSS scroll snap is probably the better solution but you could also watch for the scroll event on the page and scroll directly to the next section by doing some window height calculations (based on your current one). Or just scroll to an anchor with a hash everytime you see a scroll in one given direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the native [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts)

Comment: Yes, I have seen such a solution, but I would prefer the user, after using the scroll, to immediately be in the lower section than to have such freedom as here.

Comment: Maybe that's not what I meant, but I actually used your idea and it seems to me the fastest and most optimal. Thank you very much.